# Iterating through elements in a list from different index positions

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

This should be an easy one but I have simply not come to a solution.
This is the exercise:

> Start with 4 words “comfortable”, “round”, “support”, “machinery”, return a list of all possible 2 word combinations.
>
> Example: `["comfortable round", "comfortable support", "comfortable machinery", ...]`

I have started coding a loop that would go through every element, starting with the element at `index[0]` :

```
words = ["comfortable, ", 'round, ', 'support, ', 'machinery, ']
index_zero= words[0]


for i in words:
    words = index_zero + i
    words_one = index_one + i 
    print(words)
```

```
>>> Output=
comfortable, comfortable,
comfortable, round,
comfortable, support,
comfortable, machinery
```

The issue is when I want to start iterating from the 2nd element ('round'). I have tried operating the indexes (`index[0] + 1`) but of course, it won't return anything as the elements are strings.
I know a conversion from string to indexes needs to take place, but I'm not sure how.

I have also tried defining a function, but it will return None

```
word_list = ["comfortable, ", 'round, ', 'support, ', 'machinery, ']
index_change = word_list[0]+ 1

def word_variations(set_of_words):
    for i in set_of_words:
        set_of_words = set_of_words[0] + i


set_of_words = word_variations(word_list)   
print(set_of_words)
```

Comment: `for i in words[1:]:`

Comment: Also, your function doesn't have a `return`

Comment: Are you looking for combinations or permutations ?  Some of the solutions below give you Permutations, where ('round, ','support, ') and (support, ','round, ') are both output as two different things.  Combinations would only output one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would do what you're looking for:

```py
def word_variations(word_list):
  combinations = []
  for first_word in word_list:
    for second_word in word_list:
      if first_word != second_word:
        combinations.append(f'{first_word}, {second_word}')

  return combinations

word_list = ["comfortable", "round", "support", "machinery"]
print(word_variations(word_list))
```

Explanation:

You need to include a return statement at the end of the function to return a value. In my example function `word_variations()`, I first define an empty list called `combinations`. This will store each combination we compute. Then I iterate through all the words in the input `word_list`, create another inner loop to iterate through all words again, and if the `first_word` does not equal the `second_word` append the combination to my `combinations` list. Once all loops are complete, return the finished list from the function.

If I slightly change the code to print each of the results on a new line:

```py
def word_variations(word_list):
  combinations = []
  for first_word in word_list:
    for second_word in word_list:
      if first_word != second_word:
        combinations.append(f'{first_word}, {second_word}')

  return combinations

word_list = ["comfortable", "round", "support", "machinery"]

for combo in word_variations(word_list):
  print(combo)
```

the output is:

```
comfortable, round
comfortable, support
comfortable, machinery
round, comfortable
round, support
round, machinery
support, comfortable
support, round
support, machinery
machinery, comfortable
machinery, round
machinery, support
```

Comment: Hello Kyle ! You are a star ! This solution does work perfectly. I'm slighly new to Python and I was wondering if you could tell me what is this line from your code doing?  I do undestand is adding the elements to the empty list, but I'm not sure what the f' stands for : combinations.append(f'{first_word}, {second_word}')

Comment: @DianaGalindo absolutely! the "f" stands for [format string or "f-string"](https://zetcode.com/python/fstring/). It's a clean, readable way to concatenate your strings with variables. When placing an f before your quotation marks, it allows you to place a variable or expression between curly braces and then just type extra characters between or around it. I used it in this case so that you don't need to include the comma and space in your input list. Instead, the way I used f-string adds the comma and space while adding the new combination to your list.

Comment: @DianaGalindo btw, there are many ways to format your strings. The older method used was `.format()`  ie.`'My name is {}'.format('Kyle')` This was an okay solution but isn't as readable. You could also concatenate your strings using the `+` operator. AFAIK, the most widely used formating in most programming languages is some form of f-strings so they are a good habit to use.

Comment: Hello @KyleDixon, thank you for explaining. I have seen .format() before, but I had no idea it was updated to f'. This makes complete sense. Thank you for linking to the resource page for 'f-string' too !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with indexes in a Python loop like that, you should use either [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) or iterate over the length of the list. The following examples will start the loop at the second element.

Example getting both index and the word at once with `enumerate`:

```
for i, word in enumerate(set_of_words[1:]):
```

Example using only indexes:

```
for i in range(1, len(set_of_words)):
```

Note: `set_of_words[1:]` above is a [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#:%7E:text=In%20addition%20to%20indexing%2C%20slicing%20is%20also%20supported.%20While%20indexing%20is%20used%20to%20obtain%20individual%20characters%2C%20slicing%20allows%20you%20to%20obtain%20substring%3A) that returns the list starting at the second element.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `itertools.permutations()` like this

```py
from itertools import permutations

lst = ['comfortable', 'round', 'support', 'machinery']

for i in list(permutations(lst, 2)):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Hello there! Thank you for this solution. It has helped me to look at the difference between combination and permutation (and their methods in Python).

Comment: You're always welcome